Proof that Torus is a 2-dim submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^3$ using parametrization
I want to show that the torus $T:=\{(x, y, z) \in\mathbb{R}^3 \mid (\sqrt{x^2+y^2}-R)^2+z^2=r^2\}\subset \mathbb{R}^3, 0<r<R<\infty$ is a 2-dimensional submanifold showing that

$\forall p\in T \space \exists \text{ open subsets } U\subseteq \mathbb{R}^3, D\subseteq\mathbb{R}^2, p\in U \text{ and } \gamma\in C^1(D;\mathbb{R}^3)$ such that $ \forall x\in D: D\gamma (x) \text{ has full rank and } T\cap U = \gamma(D)$.

I consider the parametrization $$\gamma(s,t):=\left(\begin{array}{c}(R+r\cos(s))\cos(t)\\ (R+r\cos(s))\sin(t) \\ r\sin(s) \end{array}\right), D\gamma(s,t)= \left (\begin{array}{cc}-r\cos(t)\sin(s) & -\sin(t)(R+r\cos(s)) \\-r\sin(t)\sin(s) & \cos(t)(R+r\cos(s)) \\r\cos((s) & 0 \end{array} \right)$$ but I'm not sure how to define U:  Obviously, I can't just take $[0, 2\pi]\times[0, 2\pi]$ as it is not open in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and I can't figure out how the period of the trigonometric functions acts here. Can somebody help me?
Thank you in advance!
Edit:
Let $(x, y, z) \in \gamma(\mathbb{R}^2)$, i.e. $x = (R+r\cos(s))\cos(t), y=(R+r\cos(s))\sin(t), z=r\sin(s)$ for some $(s,t)\in\mathbb{R}^2$. Then
$$(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}-R)^2+z^2=(\sqrt{((R+r\cos(s))\cos(t))^2+((R+r\cos(s))\sin(t))^2}-R)^2+(r\sin(s))^2=(\sqrt{(R+r\cos(s))^2(\cos^2(t)+\sin^2(t))}-R)^2+r^2sin^2(s)=(R+r\cos(s)-R)^2+r^2\sin^2(s)=r^2(\cos^2(s)+sin^2(s))=r^2$$
Therefore $\gamma(s,t)\in T$.
$\leadsto  $ is this true?

Your edit proved that
$$T=\gamma(\Bbb R^2),$$
where
$$\gamma(s,t):=\left((R+r \cos s)\cos t,(R+r\cos s)\sin t,r\sin t\right)$$
You already checked that $D\gamma(s,t)$ has full rank ($\forall(s,t)\in\Bbb R^2$).
For any $p=\gamma(s_0,t_0)\in T$, let $D:=(s_0-\pi,s_0+\pi)\times(t_0-\pi,t_0+\pi)$, $\Gamma:=\gamma((\{s_0+\pi\}\times\Bbb R)\cup(\Bbb R\times\{t_0+\pi\}))$ (union of two circles) and $U:=\Bbb R^3\setminus\Gamma$. Then, $U$ is an open subset of $\Bbb R^3$ and $\gamma(D)=T\cap U$.

Thank you for your Answer! I added an edit to my initial question regarding the compatibility of the parametrization, can you tell me why that is wrong?

Sorry you are right.
